# Question about homomorphisms and kernels and cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was reading my textbook on abstract algebra and I have run into a theorem about homomorphisms and cosets and how every kernel of a homomorphism of G into G' is normal subgroup H. my question is why are cosets of G collapsed they way they are? I don't understand it.

The part I read was just in reference to the kernel, but what about other cosets, is it the same with them as well

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *collapsed* ?

Comment: I have a diagram in my book aND it's showing the kernel H aND it's cosets being collapsed into the coset represenatives. I'm curious, is this the case with all cosets, or just this one with the kernel? Why do we care about the elements of our homomorphism that get turned into the identity element in G'?

Answer (score 3):

Cosets along a subgroup $H$ in a group $G$ are a vast generalisation of congruence classes in integers.

They're a special kind of a partition of the group, and thus define an *equivalence* relation on that group. All cosets are in bijection, i. e.  if the group is  *finite*, they have the same number of elements. Furthermore, if the subgroup is *normal*, this equivalence relation is compatible with the group structure of $G$, which allows to define a groups structure on  the set of cosets, denoted by $G/H$ – exactly as from the additive group structure of $\mathbf Z$, one deduces a group structure on $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$.

Working with the quotient group $G/H$ amounts to consider all elements of a coset as representing a single element.